# jQuery Copy text inside iframe to main document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hopefully someone here can help me with this challenge!
I have a parent page which is the checkout page for an e-commerce site. It's run on zencart and for every order placed a table row is generated through ZenCart. I've setup an EACH function which generates an iframe for an artwork uploader for each TR (order) found. The uploader works and the correct number of instances are being generated.

I wanted to avoid an iFrame, but the uploader script I purchased will not permit me to load it directly into the zencart page template, or via AJAX (tried both). There's some kind of major resource/path situation going on when doing it this way... so I've resorted to iframes.

I'm able to call JS on file-upload-complete. At that point I'm trying to capture the name of the filename that was just uploaded and place it inside the TR. The problem I'm running into are permission error when trying to access the iframe contents.

I've tried everything I've come across on this site and many others, so believe it isn't a problem with the selectors/frame selection... Firebug is telling me that I'm getting permission errors when trying to access the iframe, yet they're both on the same domain and the src is being set by a relative path....

I'm completely lost, any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!
www.prothings.com/store
Add items to the cart and go to checkout.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863744/same-origin-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to access main `window` or `window.document` from inside an iframe you should change the context by using `window.parent`
For example when you want to append some text to a div, you should do something like this

```
window.parent.$.('#theDiv').text('the text');
```

There is a bug in IE when you run the code from inside the `iframe` and remove the `iframe` in between. IE can't run the code in the fly