# How to remote click on links from a 3rd party website

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cookies

I have a problem that I am trying to conceptualize whether possible or not. Nothing too fancy (i.e. remote login or anything etc.)

I have Website A and Website B.

On website A a user selects on a few links from website B, i would like to then remotely click on behalf of the user on the link (as Website B creates a cookie with the clicked information) so when the user gets redirected to Website B, the cookie (and the links) are pre-selected and the user does not need to click on them one by one.

Can this be done?

Comment: This is not possible. If it was possible there would be massive security flaws in all browsers.

Comment: Read up on the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Here is more information on Same Origin Policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863744/same-origin-policy (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to interact to anorher webservice the resolution is send post/get request and parse response
Question is what is your goal?